# Base64encode image string gets truncated

Tags: php, html, angularjs

My string is truncated. I can't get the original string.

```
$img_file = product6.jpg';
$imgData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($img_file));
$src = 'data:image/jpg;base64,'.$imgData;
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have missing single quotes

```
$img_file = 'product6.jpg';
```